# Oceanic vs. Suunto Dive Watches

Tags: equipment, scuba-diving

I've had my Suunto D4 dive watch for about 6 years now and its served me well. A dive instructor recently spoke quite highly about her oceanic watch (she didnt have it on her at the time). I'm just wondering if anyone out there has ever owned an Oceanic and can compare it to a Suunto for me ?

One thing I've noticed is that my Suunto's strap has a propensity to snap a lot.

Comment: What feature do you think you need, that the Suunto doesn't have? See if you can get a bungee mount for the Suunto, they are much better than straps.

Comment: I'm not really looking to buy a new watch. This more of an exploratory discussion. The question could be re-phrased to say what have you noticed is better/worse between a Suunto and an Oceanic in terms of interface or features for example ?

Comment: Per our [help center](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."

Comment: That said, the [current answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/7294) addresses how to select a watch. That is more helpful to the community.

Answer (score 2):

Brands are meaningless. What you need to look at is PRICE, FUNCTIONS/FEATURES, READABILITY, EASE OF USE.

So take various dive computers arrange them based on price range you can afford then see what features/functions each one has. Remove the computers that do not have the features you require. Then compare what is left out and see which one is best value for money, based on the criteria you deem important.

My suggestion/opinion is that a dive computer must be easy to read even at depth, must have a back light, must have audible warnings, must have adjustable warning settings, must give warnings for ascent rates, safety stops, exceeding depth & time on a dive.

Comment: If I look at the specs of the D4, I think for normal recreational scuba diving you have everything you could need from a dive computer.  - http://www.suunto.com/Products/dive-computers-and-instruments/Suunto-D4i-Novo/Suunto-D4i-Novo-Gray/

Answer (score -1):

The brand is too general, so let me guess, I would say maybe Oceanic Atom 3.1 versus Sunnto D4i.

To answer your question about "better/worse between a Suunto and an Oceanic in terms of interface or features.." I noticed something that,

The Suunto D4i is actually recommended dive computer for every leisure diver, I mean to fun or recreational diver. So, no matter level of skill, expert or newbies, it is totally great. of course it is also depend on the price range that people could afford it. Furthermore, the computer is readable along with user-friendly display, very easy to read via user interface together with the documentation.

But, the Oceanic Atom is loaded with numerous advanced functions and could be recommended dive computer for technical diving, or expert diving together with the complex user documentation. It provides the diver a chance to stretch out our under the sea activities to higher limitations. Oceanic Atom 3 is actually all around dive watch computer for expert divers, because it has all possible capabilities to dive with 3 gas mixes and also to handle 4 dive modes. I do believe that newbies will discover this dive computer complicated.

So, the verdict, I think that, no wonder a certain dive instructor will talk about the Oceanic, because of it is made for the experts.

Comment: Just like [this Health.SE post](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/15755/7205) you need to declare your affiliation with this website.

Comment: I've removed the website link from this answer. Please do not re-add it without making clear what affiliation you have, if any, with the website.